# Laravel - Sorting a query based on occurrence of array of words

Tags: php, database, laravel

With the following code i am able to get required data but i want to sort also.

Lets say it found only 3 rows,
on first it found a match of one word
on second it found a match of two words
on third it found a match of one word.

```
$keyword = "metal chairs";
$keywordArr = explode(" ", $keyword);

$productData = $productData->where(function ($query) use ($keyword, $MykeywordArr) {
    $query->orWhere('products.name', 'like', $keyword . '%');
    $query->orWhere('products.info', 'like', $keyword . '%');
    foreach ($MykeywordArr as $keywordKey => $keywordValue) {
        $query->orWhere('products.name', 'like', '%' . $keywordValue . '%');
        $query->orWhere('products.info', 'like', '%' . $keywordValue . '%');
    }
});

// sorting for $productData goes here:
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you are wanting to sort the entries based on the number of hits the keyword(s) have in each entry. I wrote a simple search library for Eloquent that can help with this. It ranks the entries based on the number of times each keyword occurs in the given fields (which you can customize), and returns it as a Laravel Collection.
Check it out here: [glmdev/search on Github](https://github.com/glmdev/search).

It will give your model a `search()` method like so:

```
$products = $productData->search("metal chairs");
```

If you just really need to re-implement it yourself, the code for how I sorted the models by keyword [is available here.](https://github.com/glmdev/search/blob/master/src/Search.php)

Comment: Both of the method not working in my case. is it with the version ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? If you can't make use of the library, here it is rewritten as a standalone function: https://gist.github.com/glmdev/60a01e6fe0fcf0eab16ae3ee016919ea

Just include the functions as helpers somewhere and call `search($collectionOfModels, 'metal chairs', ['name', 'info'])` and it should return a sorted collection.

Comment: version is 5.5.2

Comment: Is there any difference btw collection and a variable contains select data from table?

Comment: also i am applying above "search" on a variable contains select data.

Comment: Yes. The `$productData->where()` method returns a Query object. When you call it, it needs to end with the `get()` call, like so: `$productData->where(...)->get();`. That will cause the query to be executed and will return a Collection object.